# Getting parameter for a method from a method that didn't call it

Tags: java, methods

Wondering how I would go about this hopefully the title made some sense.

If not, here's an example:

var1 is in the main method

main method calls method1

method1 calls method2

method2 calls method3

method3 calls method4

method4 calls method5

method5 wants to user var1

Obviously it's pretty deep down the hierarchy. So having each method call var1 seems silly to me.

Is there a way to get method5 to call the var1 from the main method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all methods are in the same class you can make it a class level variable by declaring it at the start of your class. You can either make it `static` so that any instance of the class can access the same data or have an individual value per instance without the `static` modifier.

```
// static variable shared across all instances
private static Type variable;
// static public is accessible to all classes
public static Type variable;
// access with YourClasss.variable
// or only available internally
private Type variable;
```

Alternatively you can either give public access to the variable either directly by declaring the variable public or through a public getter method.

```
// accessible by any class
public Type variable;
// controlled access through a getter
private Type variable;
public Type getVariable() {
    return variable;
}
```

You should read up on [Java's variable modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)